# Core Web vitals CLS(Comulative Layout Shift) failed for my website

Tags: php, reactjs, next.js, pagespeed-insights, core-web-vitals

Core Web vitals CLS(Cumulative Layout Shift) failed for my website when Computed from the Core Web Vitals metrics over the latest 28-day collection period in google page speed Insights on https://bbbootstrap.com/snippets/bootstrap-5-sidebar-menu-toggle-button-34132202.

But Diagnose performance issues shows CLS(Cumulative Layout Shift - 0) I am not able to find the issue.

Screenshot of the Issue - https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbD0k.png

Answer (score 0):

The Diagnose section just does a cold load of the page, without any interaction or scrolling, whereas the real users section measures the CLS during the life of your page where they are doing these things.

If you use the [Web Vitals extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-vitals/ahfhijdlegdabablpippeagghigmibma?hl=en) and enable logging in the console and client around your site (for example by clicking on the Resource tab) you will see CLS is logged.

Another example is that loading that page doesn't appear to create any shifts. But reloading the page does a weird scroll-y thing where it loads the a bit down the page, and then scrolls up? And I also see CLS logged in the console.

This article gives some more information on how you can gather real-user shift data in your analytics to help identify issues like this: https://web.dev/debug-performance-in-the-field/